# NSString dataUsingEncoding -- which encoding works on Windows and Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encoding, nsstring

I am creating a CSV file from an `NSString` like this:

```
NSData *csvFile = [csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

That makes problems with umlauts.
If I use `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` it works for Windows and if I use `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` it works only on the Mac. 
By "works", I mean the umlauts and some special characters like euro sign are shown properly and not like some funny characters or invisible.

What do you use to work on both Windows and Mac?

Comment: UTF8 should support the umlaut, do you have an example string, and what are you trying to print the umlaut to? a label or the console?

Comment: I am exporting the string to CSV File (NSData). If i print it in the console, before exporting, it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

UTF8 is supporting Umlauts, however on the windows side you also need an UTF8-aware application to read the CSV.

To make sure everything is OK, you could also take a look at the file in a hex editor, or a text editor, which supports UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Not just supports UTF-8, but is set to use it. Even TextEdit on the Mac, before Lion, would default to viewing text files as MacRoman or ISO 8859-1 or something if you didn't specifically tell it to use UTF-8.

Comment: you are right, I just thought it was obvious. Thanks for clarifying this (+1).